# install TrueType font on fedora 14

Tags: linux, fonts, fedora-14

i would like install  tahoma on fedora 14 i create a folder **.fonts** name in copied my tahoma font in this folder and run this command fc-cache -f in my terminall

but i cant use in this font yet,
 how should i install fonts in fedora 14?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the font file called Tahoma.ttf?

What does

```
fc-list | grep -i tahoma
```

say?

What happens when you run

```
fc-cache -v
```

?  Does your ~/.fonts directory appear in the output?

This is what it looked like when I just added some fonts in my ~/.fonts.

```
$ fc-cache -v
/usr/share/fonts: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 3 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 3 dirs
...
/usr/share/fonts/truetype: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 8 dirs
...
/home/username/.fonts: caching, new cache contents: 3 fonts, 0 dirs
/var/cache/fontconfig: not cleaning unwritable cache directory
/home/username/.fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
fc-cache: succeeded
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your fonts in /usr/share/fonts. Also have a look at this overview - it's still valid for Fedora 14 (I'm running it right now) and I'd at least suggest turning on the bytecode interpreter:

http://linuxtweaking.blogspot.com/2010/03/fedora-12-improving-awful-font.html

Edit: If you follow the instructions on that page, the freetype package is installed as follows:

```
yum install freetype-freeworld
```

(not freeworld-freetype!)

Answer (score 0):

Restart the program you want to use the font in. Also, it's `~/.fonts`; the location of the directory is important.

Comment: i did , but i cant see this font in my font lists