# How can I install Windows fonts in Fedora 14?

Tags: linux, fonts, fedora

How can I install Windows fonts in Fedora 14? I need to install some fonts that support my language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [install TrueType font on fedora 14](http://superuser.com/questions/221911/install-truetype-font-on-fedora-14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read [this post](http://linuxhelp.blogspot.com/2005/12/adding-windows-fonts-in-linux.html), it shows different methods of installing fonts, just make sure you have a Windows installation handy to save the Fonts from.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple. As root, copy the fonts over to `/usr/share/fonts/TTF` then run the command `fc-cache`.

```
su --login
cp /path/to/windows-font.ttf /usr/share/fonts/TTF
fc-cache
```